# every reload echo old number

Tags: php, session

When I reload my page, every time the count is `2`. How do I add `1` to the old count instead?

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['attmpt'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['attmpt'] = $_SESSION['attmpt'] + 1;

    echo $_SESSION['attmpt'];
```

Comment: :-) exactly!  Did you want something else to happen?

Comment: I want to Add 1 to each reload, 1+1, 2+1, 3+1. but my code is always tell 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're always setting `$_SESSION['attmpt']` to `1` on page load. You need to modify your code as follows:

```
session_start();

if( !isset($_SESSION['attmpt']) )
{
    $_SESSION['attmpt'] = 1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['attmpt'] += 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['attmpt'];
```

Comment: I test out this code. it shows 1 at every time. I want to +1 at every reload.

Comment: @SchoolforDesign Sorry, there was a typo. Please try the edited code.

Answer (score 2):

that's because you set `$_SESSION['attmpt']` to 1 each time, so, 1 + 1 = 2. Every time. do like this:

```
$_SESSION['attmpt'] = (isset($_SESSION['attmpt']) ? $_SESSION['attmpt'] + 1 : 1);
```

this will keep your number

Comment: why your code at every reload tell `1` ? I want to add +1

Comment: @SchoolforDesign it doesn't, if your session is set, then it equals the session set variable, else it equals 1 - this is just one line of your script. not the full script xD

Comment: I posted all the code. simply I want to +1 to my session `$_SESSION['attmpt'] = 1;` at every reload.

Comment: @SchoolforDesign updated code as you obviously replaced all your code with the above?